# PL/SQL Function to check whether a number is prime or not

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Please find the error and rectify this code**

This is a PL/SQL function to check whether a number is prime or not
By using the flag method instead of using count to check the requirement, it's working perfectly but not for this method.

```
create or replace function isprime(x in number)
RETURN number
IS
i int;
count int;
BEGIN
count:=0;
for i in 2..x/2 LOOP
if mod(x,i)=0 then
count:=count+1;
end if;
end loop;
return count;
end;
/
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

DECLARE
n int;
c int;
BEGIN
n:=&n;
c:=isprime(n);
if c=0 then
dbms_output.put_line(n||'is a prime number');
else
dbms_output.put_line(n||'is not prime');
end if;
end;
/

Enter value for n: 5
old   5: n:=&n;
new   5: n:=5;
c:=isprime(n);
   *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 4:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.ISPRIME is invalid
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Here is the error list:

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION ISPRIME:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
10/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
10/8     PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a
         SQL statement only

13/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
13/8     PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a
         SQL statement only
```

Comment: You could maintain an indexed table of all prime numbers, sort of like a calendar table approach.  This would avoid ugly and non-performant UDF calls all over the place.

Comment: `COUNT`is a reserved SQL word. Just use a different name, e.g. `v_count` (the prefix v is often used for variable names in PL/SQL). Your code would be more readable with proper indention, by the way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen *All* prime numbers? :-)

Comment: @TonyAndrews It depends on how large of a number the OP is expecting, but yes I am suggesting this.

Comment: That is going to be a large table :D The type `NUMBER` allows 38 digits, so that would be more than an undecillion prime numbers, if I'm not mistaken. (I had to google both, the formula for an approximate count and the name for 10^36 :-) On the other hand: The calculation with PL/SQL would also take some time for such big numbers :D

Comment: I'd imagine this is more of a college assignment than a business requirement, so maintaining a look-up table of primes would probably not be an acceptable solution :-)

Comment: And needless(?) to say that you should loop to sqrt(x), skip the even numbers, and return as soon as you find a divisor (and you can optimize even more)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . And there would *still* be an uncountable number of prime numbers not in the table!

Comment: After resolving the syntax issues and applying some optimizations this still has a major problem. It will consider 1, 0, and all negative numbers as prime, and you cannot guarantee every parameter value will be a positive integer. And what happens with non integer values.

Comment: Yeah I got my mistake. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

COUNT is reserve sql word, have a look at this as an alternative solution for this task.

```
DECLARE
  value_   NUMBER default :A;
  i     NUMBER DEFAULT 5;
  is_prime VARCHAR2(5 CHAR);
BEGIN
  IF value_ = 2 OR value_ = 3 THEN
  is_prime := 'TRUE';
  ELSIF MOD(value_,2)=0 OR MOD(value_,3)=0 OR value_ <= 1 THEN
  is_prime := 'FALSE';
  END IF;
  
  WHILE POWER(i,2) <= value_ LOOP
  IF MOD(value_,i)=0 OR MOD(value_,i + 2)=0 THEN 
  is_prime := 'FALSE';
  exit;
  END IF;
  i := i + 6;  
  end loop;
  is_prime := nvl(is_prime,'TRUE');  
  DBMS_Output.Put_Line(is_prime||' IT IS '||CASE is_prime WHEN 'FALSE' THEN 'NOT' END||'A PRIME NUMBER');
END;
```